# Blank Page on deploy app using Github Pages (Angular)

Tags: angular, deployment, github-pages

after deploy my app using GitHub Pages it shows me a blank page as you can see:

https://pelourinhopos.github.io/FrontEnd/

I have already tried a lot of things to solve this but I dont know whats happening, can someone help me?

This is my github project repo:

https://github.com/PelourinhoPOS/FrontEnd

Answer (score 0):

Github pages deploys your site to a subfolder so you need to build your site according to that

adding the --base-href flag to your build command builds your site to be hosted from a sub directory

```
ng build --base-href=/subfolder/
```